# How to get selected menu option from a knockout.js observableArray?

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, knockout.js

I feel like I'm missing something very basic, but I can't get a dropdown menu to work as I expect using Knockout.js.

I have a set of objects I want to present in a menu, and I need to find the selected option and post that to the server. I can get the menu to render, but  can't seem to get the value of the selected item. My view model looks like this:

```
function ProjectFilterItem( name, id ) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Id   = id;
}

function FilterViewModel() {
    this.projectFilters = ko.observableArray([
        new ProjectFilterItem( "foo", "1" ),
        new ProjectFilterItem( "bar", "2" ),
        new ProjectFilterItem( "baz", "3" )
    ]);
    this.selectedProject = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings( new FilterViewModel() );
```

and my view markup looks like this:

```
<select 
    id        = "projectMenu"   
    name      = "projectMenu"
    data-bind = "
        options:        projectFilters,
        optionsText:    'Name', /* I have to enquote the value or I get a JS error */
        optionsValue:   'Id',   /* If I put 'selectedProject here, nothing is echoed in the span below */
        optionsCaption: '-- Select Project --'
    "
></select>

<b>Selected Project:</b> <span data-bind="text: selectedProject"></span>
```

How do get the selected menu item to display in the span, and to post to the server? (I assume the observable I render in the span is the same one I'd post.) Do I need another property in the `ProjectFilterItem`, like `this.selected = ko.observable(false);` ? If so, how would I declare it as the target of the value?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need use with the [`value` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) to bind the selected value:

From the [`options` documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html):

> Note: For a multi-select list, to set which of the options are
>   selected, or to read which of the options are selected, use the
>   **selectedOptions binding**. For a single-select list, you can also read
>   and write the selected option using the **value binding**.

In your example:

```
<select 
    id        = "projectMenu"   
    name      = "projectMenu"
    data-bind = "
        value: selectedProject,
        options:        projectFilters,
        optionsText:    'Name',
        optionsValue:   'Id',
        optionsCaption: '-- Select Project --'
    "
></select>
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AZ9Cn/).

Comment: d'oh! I missed that in the doc -- I was concentrating on the parameters section at the bottom, and read right past the note at the top. Thanks, problem solved!