# Knockout.js DDL change event

Tags: knockout.js

Anyone knows how to pass on entire object while change an event.

VIEW:

```
<select data-bind="foreach: controlConfig, event: { change: selectionChanged }, value: $data">
  <option data-bind="text: $data.Name"></option>
</select>
```

VIEWMODEL:

```
self.selectionChanged = function (data, event) {
            alert("the other selection changed " + data.Name);
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get selected menu option from a knockout.js observableArray?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240658/how-to-get-selected-menu-option-from-a-knockout-js-observablearray)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.For select element should be used a special binding - `options`.

```
<select data-bind="options: controlConfig, value: selectedConfig"></select>
```

2.To handle selecting item in dropdown, you need to use [the value binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) to bind the selected value "`selectedConfig`" then subscribe to it:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.controlConfig = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedConfig = ko.observable();
    self.selectedConfig.subscribe(function(newVal) {
        // your code here...
    }); 
}
```

Kindly check this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706784/knockoutjs-how-to-get-the-selected-option-arrayobject)